# How is this conditional parsed?

Tags: c++

For some context, the conditional is used in the normal type of algorithm for finding linked list cycles:

From link: http://vijayinterviewquestions.blogspot.com/2007/05/how-would-you-detect-loop-in-linked.html

```
p=head;
q=head->next;

while(p!=NULL && q!=NULL) {
    if(p==q) { //Loop detected! exit(0); }

    p=p->next;
    q=(q->next)?(q->next->next):q->next;
}

// No loop.
```

What does the line:

```
q=(q->next)?(q->next->next):q->next;
```

get parsed as though?  I'm a little confused about operator precedence in this conditional - does q take the value of the left hand side of the ? or of the whole conditional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

that can be expanded to:

```
if (q->next) {
  q = q->next->next;
} else {
  q = q->next;
}
```

Comment: Not completely equivalent. The result of the ternary expression always has the same type, even if the types of the subexpressions differ. This can lead to some very unintuitive behavior if you expect it to work like this.

Answer (score 2):

Its called the [ternary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_C.23.2C_Vala.2C_Objective-C.2C_Java.2C_JavaScript.2C_ActionScript) operator and it means

```
if(q->next)
  q->next->next;
else
  q->next;
```

Answer (score 1):

It takes the value of the whole conditional expression, since the assignment operator has [very low precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) (second only to `throw` and `,`). The expression in your question is equivalent to:

```
q = q->next ? q->next->next : q->next;
```

In order for the assignment to take priority, you would have to write something like:

```
(q = q->next) ? q->next->next : q->next;
```

Which, of course, always assigns `q->next` to `q`, then proceeds to evaluate one of the remaining conditional operands into thin air.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing an example of the ternary operator.

`q=(q->next)?(q->next->next):q->next;`

can also be read as:

```
if(q->next)
{
    q = (q->next->next)
}
else
{
    q = q->next;
}
```

The ternary operator has precedence lower than most other operators (excepting the comma operator, "throw" and all assignment operators).

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at an [operator precedence table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) you'll see that the ternary operator `?:` is near the bottom of the list. This means that the subexpressions within it will be evaluated first. The parenthesis within this grouping just reinforce the fact; they were probably added for readability.

The beginning of the expression `(q->next)` is evaluated to see if it is true or not by comparing to zero; in the case of a pointer, a NULL pointer is zero or false and any other value is true.

The result of a ternary operator will be the first expression after the `?` if the part to the left of the `?` is true, otherwise it will be the expression after the `:`.